# woocommerce - Update variable product attribut with a variable passed in a web link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I develop a website to sell my prints. I have more than 100 photos but I do not want to create as many products in my shop. So I just created one product with associated attributes (size, finish ...). In my galleries, when I click on a photo to open the product page, I would like to send the name of the photo in a variable via the product page web link so that it is integrated into the product as an attribute. How can I do that ?

Thank you all for the help ;)

Comment: In fact, I think I need to create by code a new product (if not exisiting) each time a photo is selected. What do you think about that ?

Comment: What about duplicate by code the "template" product and set the photo reference to the new product name ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I coded some lines. This function duplicate a product (template) and update title of the new product with a variable passed in a web link then redirect to the new product page.

```
function duplicate_product() {

//Image reference from web link (../produit/tirage-sur-commande/?image=xxx)
$img =  $_GET['image'];

if ($img != '') {//Only if $img has a value

    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/produit/tirage-sur-commande/') === 0) {//Only if template product is 'selected' 

    //Check if Product with same reference already exists
    require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/post.php';
    if ( post_exists( $img ) == 0 ) {//If not exists: duplicate product

        //Duplicate product
        $wc_adp = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product; 
        $dproduct = $wc_adp->product_duplicate( wc_get_product( '3386' ) );

        //New Product Id 
        $new_id = $dproduct ->get_id();

        // Update product
        $new_pdct = array(
            'ID'           => $new_id,
            'post_title'   => $img,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        wp_update_post( $new_pdct );
    }
    //Open new product page
    $url = home_url( '/' ) . 'produit/' . $img;
    wp_redirect( $url );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: be careful because the function post_exists( 'post_title' ) also consider medias title ! So if no post with 'post title' exists but in media, the function will return the media ID